# Prove that if polynomial $f(x) = x^6 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ null places are real, then$ a = b = c = d = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

if polynomial [image] null places are all real, then how can i show that $a = b = c = d = 0$?

[image: Simplifixed polynomial]

$x(x(0x + 0 + x^4) + 0) + 0 => x^6 = f(x)$ ?
But that doesn't prove anything for me i think

Comment: Do you know Rolle's Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in a comment, you can use [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem): If

$$ f(x) = x^6 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$$

has 6 real zeros (counted with multiplicity) then

$$ f'(x) = 6x^5 + 3a x^2 + 2b x + c$$

has 5 real zeros. Repeating this argument twice it follows that

$$ f'''(x) = 120x^3 + 6a $$

has 3 real zeros (with multiplicity). This is possible only if $a = 0$.

Now work backwards: If

$$ f''(x) = 30x^4 + 2b$$

has 4 real zeros then $b = 0$, and so on ...